# "undefined method" error ruby

Tags: ruby

I am learning ruby and finding difficulty in accessing a class global variable through its object. Here is how I was trying to access it:

**Code inside MyController class:**

```
class MyController
    def create
       my_params = MyClass.new params
       p my_params.content
    end
end
```

***Code inside MyClass class:***

```
class MyClass
    def initialize(content)
      @content = content
    end
end
```

When I print criteria, the output is:

```
"#<MyClass:0x007fc473bfda58 @content={\"key1\"=>value1, \"key2\"=>value2}>"
```

I am trying to print the data inside "content" variable and so I tried `my_params.content`.
With this I am getting "undefined method `content" error and I understand its because I am trying access a variable using method calling convention/syntax.

I want to print @content variable from my controller. Is it possible? How do I print "content" from my controller using the variable "my_params"?

Comment: I personally do not understand what the problem is and what you are asking.

Comment: okay I will add some more info to the question. Will add the controller and the class.

Comment: you need a reader for your `@content`. please see the answer by Leo Correa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because `MyClass` has an instance variable called `@content` doesn't meant that it will automatically provide accessor methods for that variable.

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :content
end
```

If your class has that `attr_accessor` line or actually exposes the instance variable through some other method then you should be able to access it. Otherwise, Ruby doesn't actually allow you to call the instance variable name as a method directly to the instance of a class.