# I have a question with respect to some of my code for a rubygem

Tags: ruby

I am getting this issue with some of my code.

```
scraper.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in scrape_movieinfo':  undefined method `slice!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `block in each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `upto'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `each'
        from /home/empathetic-file-5230/temporary/Project1/Best50Films2018/lib/Best50Films2018/scraper.rb:12:in `block in scrape_movieinfo'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `block in each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `upto'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `each'
        from /home/empathetic-file-5230/temporary/Project1/Best50Films2018/lib/Best50Films2018/scraper.rb:8:in `scrape_movieinfo'
        from /home/empathetic-file-5230/temporary/Project1/Best50Films2018/lib/Best50Films2018/cli.rb:6:in `run'
        from bin/Best50Films2018:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: here is the code I have written up so far

Comment: A) Edit your question to include any additional details you may have forgotten on the first post. B) Describe the problem in the title, not that you have a problem or a question.

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 2):

*Next time you make a question showing an error like this, please show the code.* You commented "Here's the code." but the only code is an error message.

Based on by very limited knowledge of Ruby, your error shows that you aren't trying to call a private method, otherwise it would give you an error like this.

`private method encrypt' called for #<Person:0x007fa179863770 @name="Ada"`

The method seems to be undefined. Has it been made? ["undefined method" error ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582608/undefined-method-error-ruby) I really don't know how to answer this, there isn't much information, and I'm pretty sure that this question can't be answered without **actually showing the code.**

It might be that you are using the ‘slice!’ without any arguments.

It’s like making a method that accepts 1 variable(argument), but you called it with none.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the error message tells you that: In line `14` in your `scraper.rb` you call the `slice!` method on something that is `nil`.

What this usually means: `slice!` is a method that is defined for several different types of objects – for example: `String`, `Hash`, `Array`. Seems like in `scapper.rb:14` you think you have a variable with an instance of one of these objects, but in fact, the variable is `nil`.

Because you haven't posted your code nobody will able to tell you what went wrong and how to fix that. I suggest looking at the place at which you assign something to this variable. Or look if there is a simple typo in the variable name.